# openni_tracker and Kinects via network

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

i know that some times ago openni_tracker was able to subscribe on the topics published by the openni driver using openni_launch openni.launch However in the corrent version openni_tracker opens the openni driver on it's own. Is it still possible to subscribe on topics published to the network from remote Kinects? Is there an example about how to do this?

kind regards,
Tim

UPDATE:
the solution was particular easy. Record an oni file with the Kinect camera, than use a xn player to create a depth generator from that oni. finally generate a mockdepthgenerator from that depth generator. after a call of makewritable on the depthmap one can overwrite the depth values with the values coming from the ros topics.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54891/openni_tracker-and-kinects-via-network/) by [TimB](https://answers.ros.org/users/3336/timb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-02-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On  [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/48060/running-openni_tracker-with-multiple-kinects/) thread, I explained how to modify the tracker in order to launch it multiple times with multiple kinects.

Maybe it is modifiable in order to connect to remote kinects ? (would be better than saving oni files in my opinion)

---

Originally posted by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) with karma: 1304 on 2013-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TimB](https://answers.ros.org/users/3336/timb/) on 2013-02-17**:
i am not sure about that. It may work. However i have no idea how to instantiate a DepthGenerator or MockDepthGenerator without a physical oder simulated physical device